# Vue.js in symfony 4

Tags: symfony, vue.js

I want to use vue.js with symfony 4. 
But I have an error when i launch this command :

```
yarn encore dev-server --hot
```

Error :

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors                                                                                                                                                       20:16:47


 error  in ./assets/js/components/Hello.vue?vue&type=template&id=e8bb2c58

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| <div class="hello">
|   <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
| </div>

 @ ./assets/js/components/Hello.vue 1:0-83 30:4-35:6 30:67-35:5
 @ ./assets/js/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js
 @ ./assets/js/App.vue
 @ ./assets/js/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./assets/js/main.js

 error  in ./assets/js/App.vue?vue&type=template&id=12494949

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| <div id="app">
|   <hello></hello>
| </div>

 @ ./assets/js/App.vue 1:0-81 30:4-35:6 30:65-35:5
 @ ./assets/js/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./assets/js/main.js

 error  in ./assets/js/App.vue

vue-loader was used without the corresponding plugin. Make sure to include VueLoaderPlugin in your webpack config.

 @ ./assets/js/main.js 2:0-24
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./assets/js/main.js
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. 
I use WAMP as server.
Thanks

Comment: You should show your webpack config and package.json

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install vue-loader vue-template-compiler
```

OR

```
yarn add vue-loader vue-template-compiler
```

Comment: o/ Mark answered